# Show that a dashed spiral is not a submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, submanifold

[image]

The problem : it is a submanifold ?

My works : I tried to write this as the following set :

$$ X = \left\{ (\theta,r) \mbox{ : } r - ab^{\theta} = 0 \mbox{, } (a,b) \in \left( \mathbb{R}^{+*} \right)^2 \right\} $$

but X cannot be the curve on the picture because there are "dots"... and I don't know how to write it.

Intuitively, it is not a submanifold but can you give me some indications to show it ?

Thanks you.

Comment: What is your definition of submanifold?

Comment: I have a definition (a little bit long). But I use the following result to show that a set is a submanifold : let $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$, if $X = f^{-1}(\left\{ a \right\})$ and $f$ is a submersion for all $m \in X$ then $X$ is a submanifold of dimension $n - p$.

Comment: Look Boothby's Differentiable Manifold.